# Request for a comparison between these 3 (advanced?) functional analysis books?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, probability-distributions, book-recommendation

It would be helpful if I can get some comparison between these three books,

- T. Tao, [*An epsilon of room, I*](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-117-tao3-epsilon1.pdf), Graduate Series in Mathematics **117**, American Mathematical Society (2010).
- T. Tao [*Analysis II*](http://www.hindbook.com/index.php/analysis-ii-3-e) (3rd edition), Texts in Mathematics **38**, Hindustan Book Agency (2014).
- E. Stein, R. Shakarchi, [*Functional Analysis*](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9627.html), Princeton Lectures in Analysis **4**, Princeton University Press (2011).

---

There exists "measure theory" books by both these above authors. But I didn't include them in the above list. Though feel free to compare them too if you think that they are more closely aligned to the topics below.

---

For example which of these books is closer to things like this,  Aronszajn-Krein formula or resolvent formalism for Marchenko-Pastur distribution and such?

- I am anyway looking for a good exposition about the Aronszajn-Krein formula. 
  Any help about that?

Comment: What is Aronszajn-Krein formula. Can you briefly describe the purpose or origins or what you asked about?

Comment: You can see this recent review : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00072.pdf

Comment: None of those books are close to Aronszajn-Krein theory. They're all introductory books. Stein/Shakarchi is easier and a bit more elementary than Tao's books.

Comment: On the other hand, going through these (and otherwise enhancing your mathematical sophistication) would give you sufficient background to read *Trace Ideals and Their Application* by Barry Simon, which goes over and proves rank one Aronszajn-Krein specral theory in chapter 12. Or very many perturbation theory of linear operators books, which should include this.

Comment: I think it would also pay to look at Kato's Perturbation Theory book. He's heavily oriented toward dealing with the resolvent operator, and uses the classical spectral measure that your reference also uses. The book is large, but the exposition is clear.

Comment: Of these Barry Simon and Kato reference which gets to Aronszajn-Krein and resolvent formalism faster?